# Execute a test with a django application on gilab

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

can someone please help me. I have problems to do test on gitlab with a django application. It's about connexion to the server, I've try with postgress or mysql but nothing!!

Comment: there is not anyway anyone can help you with the information you have shared. We have no idea what the error you see is or what your gitlab set up isor what your pipeline config looks like. Please share more details

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Comment: Creating test database for alias 'default'...
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:304: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the first PostgreSQL database instead.

Comment: the reason you get the TCP connection error is your trying to connect to the db but the db failed to start. If you look in your pipeline log. `2021-08-09T16:23:37.499508500Z Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.`

Comment: `start service container: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-b7vsb8y-project-28734641-concurrent-0-661d8d0d866ecde5-postgres-1 AS /runner-b7vsb8y-project-28734641-concurrent-0-661d8d0d866ecde5-postgres-1-wait-for-service/service (docker.go:1164:3s)` So you need to trouble shoot why your postgres db isnt starting as without it django wont start

Comment: I have forked your repo and made a few changes to your ci.yaml and your settings. it runs the test now which fails but it at least runs. https://gitlab.com/uk.chris.doyle/stackoverflow-user-help/-/jobs/1489596753

Comment: I have also created the missing method your testing against and my repo now has a working version of your code and a valid test that runs

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it on my computer.